# Python error: Valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf

In python when I run this code:

```
lat, lon = f.variables['latitude'], f.variables['longitude']
latvals = lat[:]; lonvals = lon[:] 
def getclosest_ij(lats,lons,latpt,lonpt):
dist_sq = (lats-latpt)**2 + (lons-lonpt)**2  
minindex_flattened = dist_sq.argmin()    
return np.unravel_index(minindex_flattened, lats.shape)
iy_min, ix_min = getclosest_ij(latvals, lonvals, 46.1514, 20.0846)
```

It get the following error:

> ValueError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ipython-input-104-3ba92bea5d48 in module()
>
> > ```
> > 11     return np.unravel_index(minindex_flattened, lats.shape)
> > 12     iy_min, ix_min = getclosest_ij(latvals, lonvals, 46.1514, 20.0846)
> > ```
>
> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

What does it mean? How could I fix it?
I would read a NetCDF file, it is consist of total coloumn water data with dimensions: time(124), latitude(15), and longitude(15). I would appropriate the amount of tcw for specific point (lat,lon), and time. I tried to use the code above to solve the first part of my task to evaluate the tcw for specific coorinates, but didn't work.

Thank your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python you can write

```
var1, var2 = (1, 2) # = iterable with 2 items
```

that will store 1 in `var1` and 2 in `var2`.
This feature is called unpacking.

So the error your code throws means, that the function `getclosest_ij` returned **one** value instead of the 2 values you would need to unpack them into `iy_min` and `ix_min`